# Class properties for react lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Can I write React lifecycle methods as class properties?

I've been using class properties for a while as I like the fact that I no longer have to manually bind my methods, but I'd like to keep some consistency across my components and I'm wondering if there is any drawback on writing the React lifecycle methods as class properties

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>Foo Bar</div>
    );
  }

}

export default MyComponent;
```

For example, is the context of this class property affected compared to the context in an equivalent method. Given that the `render` method in the above code is written as an arrow function, this concern seems relevant.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the edit, I miss that out, do you have any idea what this question is getting down voted?

Comment: The question is not super specific but I don't think it's entirely fair to downvote it. I'm also curious to know the answer to this question. I imagine the answer is that no, there is not downside, but someone with more experience on how React/classes work would know best

Comment: wow, the question is being stated in line one, maybe they are not familiar with the concept of class properties, hey @ZekeDroid I'd be really glad if you can help me clarify this question, edits are welcome!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are thinking with pseudo code?

Comment: @Teedub if you look at the code sample in the question, you will notice that the render method was written as an arrow function instead of a function declaration. That's a stage 3 proposal called class properties, and babel already offers support for it

Comment: @Teedub the code in the question IS that pseudo code. I don't know how to make it any more specific, I think it's a perfectly valid question and hopefully someone who knows the answer will get to it soon in case it gets closed. I'll make one addition to the question to help it out

Comment: @ZekeDroidI believe I might add a comment into the code pointing out that render is an arrow function, people might be missing that out. I'm someone sad people is downvoting it as this a legit question for me and I've had this doubt for some weeks now.

Comment: Ah yes, that was my thought, and what I edited

Comment: TY! @ZekeDroid now lets see if someone with the right knowledge can answer this

Comment: There's no functional downside, but each instantiation of that component will create a new Function instance rather than share a single `render` function on the prototype. In practice this most often does not make a difference, but if you're creating a large number of these components quickly or keeping many in memory at once, it might have an impact.

Answer (score 5):

In a way, the true answer depends on your build pipeline and what the resulting Javascript output looks like. There are two primary possibilities:

#### Input Code

Let's start by saying you are writing the following before going through any sort of pipeline transformations (babel, typescript, etc):

```
class Test {
    test = () => { console.log('test'); };
}
```

#### Output as class member variable.

In one possible world, your pipeline will also be outputting the `test` function as a member variable for the output class. In this case the output might look something like:

```
function Test() {
    this.test = function() { console.log('test'); };
}
```

This means that whenever you write `new Test()` the `test` function is going to be recreated every single time.

#### Output as class prototype function

In the other major possibility, your pipeline could be recognizing this as a function property and escape it from the class instance to the prototype. In this case the output might look something like:

```
function Test() {
}

Test.prototype = {
    test: function() { console.log('test'); }
}
```

This means that no matter how many times you call `new Test()` there will still be only one creation of the `test` function around in memory.

#### Desired behavior

Hopefully it's clear that you want your end result to have the function end up on the prototype object rather than being recreated on each class instance.

However, while you would want the function to not end up as a property, that doesn't necessarily mean you couldn't write it that way in your own code. As long as your build chain is making the correct transformations, you can write it any way you prefer.

Although, looking at the default babel settings (which your babeljs tag leads me to believe you are using) it does not make this transformation for you. You can see this in action [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKBOB7ADgU3gFwJ7QN4ChoNUINoBeaACgEoKA-PaYRAOwkRFQDoREBzKgHJipIXQC-Abmj4J-fKEgwAYgFdWwDAEs2eQkRIZa-gJAt2nHn0Eij4qQfkSgA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0). On the left I've created one class with the function as a property and one class with the function as a class method. On the right hand side, where babel shows it's output, you can see that the class with the function as a property still has it being an instance-level property, meaning it will be recreated each time that class's constructor is called.

I did find [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), which seems like it might add this transformation in, but I've not used it for myself so I'm not positive.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the most reason for writing a method as a class property is when **the method will be passed as a callback, and you need it to always be bound to the instance**. React lifecycle methods will always be called as a method, so there's no reason to bind them (and you incur a tiny memory penalty when you do). Where this makes a difference is when you're passing a function to a component as a callback (e.g. `onClick` or `onChange`).

Take this example:

```
class BrokenFoo extends React.Component {
    handleClick() {
        alert(this.props.message);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Click me
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

The function represented by `this.handleClick` is not automatically bound to the component instance, so when the method tries to read the value of `this.props` it will throw a `TypeError` because `this` is not defined. Read [this article](http://2ality.com/2014/05/this.html) if you're not familiar with `this`; the problem described in section 4.2 "Pitfall: extracting methods improperly" is essentially what's happening when you pass around a method without making sure it's bound correctly.

Here's the class, rewritten with the handler as a class property:

```
class HappyFoo extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        alert(this.props.message);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Click me
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Effectively, you can think of the `handleClick` definition in the second example as placing this code into the component's constructor (which is just about exactly the way Babel does it):

```
this.handleClick = () => {
    alert(this.props.message);
}
```

This achieves the same thing as calling `bind` on the function (as described in the linked article) but does it a little differently. Because this function is defined in the constructor, the value of `this` in `this.props.message` is bound to the containing instance. What this means is that the function is now independent of the calling context; you can pass it around and it won't break.

The rule of thumb that I follow: by default, write methods as methods. This attaches the method to the `prototype` and will usually behave the way you'd expect. However, if the method is ever written without parentheses (i.e. you're passing the value and not calling it), then you likely want to make it a class property.